# For all $E$ and $\epsilon>0$ there is $m^*(O)<m^*(e)+\epsilon$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Prove: For all $E\subseteq \mathbb{R} $ and for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an **open set** $O$, with $E\subseteq O$ such that: $$m^*(O)<m^*(e)+\epsilon$$

I am acquaint with the following:

For all $E$ and for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a covering $O$ of $E$ by **closed set** such that:

$$\sum l(O_i)\leq m^*(E)+\epsilon$$

and because the outer measure is defined as the infimum of $\sum l(O_i)$ then $$\sum l(O_i)\leq m^*(E)+\epsilon$$ as it can not be an infimum, does the same hold if the cover is an open set? it seems so, as $l(a,b)=l([a,b])$ so the countable sum will be the same too just that the proof ask $<$ whereas "my claim" is for $\leq$

Comment: Does this come from a book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, then by definition

$$m^{*}(E) = \inf\{m^*(O): O \ \text{is open and } \ E\subseteq O\}$$

Let $x$ be some element that is in the infimum. Also for $\epsilon > 0$, let $\mathcal{C}$ be a cover set of $E$ such that

$$\sum_{I\in\mathcal{C}}l(I)\leq m^*(E) + \epsilon$$

Then $O = \bigcup \mathcal{C}$ is an open set that contains $E$, so

$$x\leq m^*(O)\leq \sum_{I\in\mathcal{C}}m(I) = \sum_{I\in\mathcal{C}}l(I)\leq m^*(E) + \epsilon$$

Comment: We can use open or close cover?

Comment: I believe so, I am like 90% sure this works.